# Having trouble with translation from jQuery to Vanilla JS, doesn't work when there is multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with translating jQuery to Vanilla JS, here is my code in jQuery:

```
$("[target]").change(function () {
    var attr = $(this).attr("target");
    this.obj[attr] = this.value
});
```

And I decided to translate it to Vanilla JS, to get bettor performances (I also improved it a bit), and I came with that:

```
var addEventListener = (function() {
    if(document.addEventListener) {
        return function(element, event, handler) {
             element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
         };
    }
    else {
        return function(element, event, handler) {
             element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
        };
    }
}());
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[target]");
var obj = this.obj;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var attr = elements[i].getAttribute("target");
    addEventListener(elements[i], "change", function () {
        obj[attr] = this.value;
    });
    addEventListener(elements[i], "keydown", function () {
        obj[attr] = this.value;
    });
    addEventListener(elements[i], "input", function () {
        obj[attr] = this.value;
    });
    addEventListener(elements[i], "paste", function () {
        obj[attr] = this.value;
    });
}
```

The problem is that it works, but for only 1 element, if there is 2 or more element with the attribute "target", then, it just doesn't work properly. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Just to say, I'm using a class to integrate this code, so the `this.obj` refers to a variable that I declared in the constructor

Comment: The problem is the `attr` variable, and the fact that all four event listeners on all of your elements use the *same* `attr` variable.

Comment: "And I decided to translate it to Vanilla JS, to get bettor performances" .... why? What reason do you have to believe that *you actually need to do this*. It seems to me that you are sacrificing a ton of readability for an extremely minor performance gain that you really dont need.

Answer (score 0):

The following bit of code might be "unclean" or "improper" in some other way, but this is how I normally deal with node list traversal:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[target]'), function(x, i, a) {
    addEventListener(a[i], 'eventType', function() {
        //whatever
    });
});
```

I would've personally given the addEventListener function a different name to differentiate it from the inbuilt one.

P.S. This might help you further:
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

P.P.S. I don't think using Vanilla JS over jQuery offers a significant advantage, but that's an opinion as well.